# Count number of dictionaries in a list on condition and group by id in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I count how many items in a list of dictionaries on condition `'returned':0` and group results by `branch_id` and then return a new list?

```
current_loans = [
    {'movie_id': 1, 'branch_id': 4, 'user_id': 67,
        'loan_start': '01/05/21', 'loan_due': '10/06/21', 'returned': 0},
    {'movie_id': 1, 'branch_id': 4, 'user_id': 68,
        'loan_start': '01/05/21', 'loan_due': '05/06/21', 'returned': 0},
    {'movie_id': 1, 'branch_id': 2, 'user_id': 69,
        'loan_start': '27/04/21', 'loan_due': '26/05/21', 'returned': 1},
    {'movie_id': 1, 'branch_id': 2, 'user_id': 70,
        'loan_start': '27/04/21', 'loan_due': '26/06/21', 'returned': 0},
]
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
[
    {
        'movie_id':1, 'branch_id':4, 'No_on_loan': 2, 'closest_due_date':'05/06/21'
    },
    {
        'movie_id':1, 'branch_id':2, 'No_on_loan': 1, 'closest_due_date':'26/06/21'
    }
]
```

My best effort so far is close to what I need but not really the same:

```
get_branch_ids = [movie["branch_id"] for movie in current_loans if movie["returned"]==0]

count_onloans_per_branch = {i:all_values.count(i) for i in all_values}

print(count_onloans_per_branch)
```

This gives me a new list that only shows `branch_id` and how many items are on loan at this branch but I can't figure out how to add the `movie_id` and `closest_due_date` (the date that is the closes to today out of all dates in `loan_due` for a specific branch):

```
{4: 2, 2: 1}
```

Comment: The answer to “is it possible” is almost always “Yes” – you’re using a general-purpose language on a computer that is all but a Turing machine.  The question you may intend to ask, “how do I do it”, is too unfocused for Stack Overflow.  Repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) for the date calculations.

Comment: I have posted a pseudo code. You should go ahead and implement it - it should be easily implementable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo-code for the algorithm you need to construct the desired results from your input data.

1. Initialize an empty dictionary `resultDict`. This will hold `branch_id` as key since we are grouping by `branch_id`, and the object with required properties as value.
2. for each `loan` in `current_loans`, do 3 to 4
3. if `loan.returned` is 1, continue
4. if `loan.branch_id` does not exist in `resultDict.keys`, do 5, else do 6
5. set `resultDict[loan.branch_id]` = `{ movie_id=loan.movie_id, branch_id=loan.branch_id, No_on_loan=1, closest_due_date=loan.loan_due}`
6. a. increment `resultDict[loan.branch_id].No_on_loan` by 1
   b. set `resultDict[loan.branch_id].closest_due_date` = date closest to `today` from between `resultDict[loan.branch_id].closest_due_date` and `loan.loan_due`
7. Return the values of the dictionary `resultDict`

I can supply the code, but instead I am choosing to post it as a pseudo code.